# streaming radio windows phone from chunks of audio

Tags: windows-phone-8, android-mediaplayer, audio-streaming, mediaelement, live-streaming

I'm is someone able to point me in the right direction for playing multiple streams/AAC media either with a MediaElement or MediaPlayer. I have 3 streams that get returned from a server and this gets updated every 10 seconds so I add the new streams to the collection.

Problem is when I change the source of the MediaElement in the Media_Ended event and call Play() again it has a slight gap in the audio. What I'm wondering is if I should be creating a playlist, and if so how is this done?

I've also tried this sample: http://phonesm.codeplex.com/

but same thing when changing the source - there is a slight delay in playing the next stream/AAC link. Here's my source:

```
<mmppf:MediaPlayer x:Name="MediaPlayerPlayer"
                       Source=".AACLinkHere"
                       MediaEnded="MediaEndedChangeSource"
                       MediaEndedBehavior="Reset"
                       IsLive="True">
```

and the code behind:

```
private void MediaEndedChangeSource(object sender, Microsoft.PlayerFramework.MediaPlayerActionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MediaPlayerPlayer.SetSource(new FileStream());
            MediaPlayerPlayer.Source = new Uri(".NextAACLinkHere", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            Debug.WriteLine("*********************************************************test...adfadfadf");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

if anyone has any ideas that would be appreciated. Sample code would be even better! Cheers.